# Missing 20 Gigabyte of Free Space

Tags: internal-storage, file-system

I've recently noticed that my Galaxy Note 3 32GB model ran out of storage. My Samsung File Explorer App says that I've got about 3GB of storage left of 32GB. 
My problem now is that I can't figure out where the remaining ~30GB (I know that there aren't really 32GB of free space) are? My SDCard directory has a size of approximately 10GB, plus I've got about 6GB worth of apps. That means, I should have 16GB left (or less) instead of 3GB?

Here's a table:

Files:         10 GB
Apps:           6 GB

Free Space:     3 GB
Total Space:   32 GB

Either is the total space more like 19GB instead of 32GB (That would be kinda much, right?) or there are hiding some files somewhere worth about 10GB.

Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: Try [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Thats a big diff but maybe you use spotify with offline files or something?
Also its worth checking Settings->Storage. Click on "Cached data" for instance and clear, here you see what it taking space more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android settings you should be able to find a screen where you can see more details (probably in "Settings->Storage") about how your storage is used.

But from the list above I can see you are missing two important items that typically use storage: The Android system and the Cache. Those two items may not be available to the File Explorer app since they're not necessarily located in the user accessible location of the storage. Adding those items to your list, using the numbers I can see on my 32GB Galaxy phone as an example, the storage breakout is more along those lines:

- Android system - 6GB
- Cache - 3GB
- Apps - 6GB
- Media/Other Files - 10GB

TOTAL 25GB

This is definitely closer to the actual used space you should see you your device. If you need more room the Cache is something that can be cleaned because it contains temporary data used by your apps therefore no important data for sure.